# Reload variables values in js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react, and in my project, I have a file that defines the values for common variables I use in the app.
Some of those values are taken from cookies, so in that file, I have multiple code lines looking such as the following:

```
let myCookieValue = new cookies().get("myCookieKey");
```

What I need is not a way to manage the cookies, but a general method for refreshing the values of the variables, that in this example case - contains cookie value.
When the cookie value changes, I would like to invoke some function to refresh the myCookieValue value, but nothing seems to do this. 
What I want to do is to have all the variables declared in that js file to be refreshed/reinstantiated. How can I do it (without making that file a React component)?

Comment: Where does `new cookies()` come from? what library is this?

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are small items of data that consists of a name and a value, stored on behalf of web browsers. A Cookie can be accessed through the `document.cookie` object, but the provided interface is very primitive.

The `expiry` property allows the cookie the possibility of having an expiry date. Cookies have therefore an expiry date that will persist between browsing sessions, and only be deleted when the expiry date is reached or the user instructs the browser to do so. The value of the property can be either a date, on which the cookie will expire, or a number of seconds after which the cookie should expire.

**Clear Cookies**

A cookie can be clear using the `clear` function, which takes the cookie name as a parameter:

```
// clear the cookie
cookies().clear('myCookieKey');
```

If the cookie was set for a path or domain other than the current path and domain, these must be passed to the `clear` function through its optional second parameter:

```
// clear the site-wide cookie
cookies().clear(
    'theme',
    {
      path   : '/',
      domain : '.example.com'
    });
```